# Update ASP.NET Identity Role assignment from Code to Azure AD

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-active-directory, asp.net-identity

I am working on a ASP.NET (Blazor) server which is connected to Azure. The user management works perfectly fine and the data gets written and read to/from Azure. Anyway, I just started to work on user roles.

My first approach was to have a table in the database which contains all my users and I store my custom roles there as well. But with this approach I cannot use the Identity Platform to its fullest.

The second idea was that I use the role management directly from Azure AD. This would give me the possibility to use the Identity Platform better. But in our tool we need to manage the users and roles. Therefore, I need user roles to be updated in our app and then synced with Azure AD.

I searched around regarding this but did not find any solution regarding this. Maybe my approach is completely wrong from the get-go and someone has a completely different idea.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Usually in the Blazor Server projects where I use the `Microsoft Identity Platform` I use the [Azure RBAC (Azure role-based access control)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-implement-rbac-for-apps).

You can manage the roles using the `Azure Portal` or the `Azure Graph API`, you can check Microsoft's documentation for this one too at [Add app roles to your application and receive them in the token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I read a little bit into RBAC. The problem I have is, that we have a multi tenant application, which includes tenants outside of my organization. Therefore, I honestly do not know how those two are connected together, or if there are any problems at all. Regarding the API: This sounds amazing, especially if it really looks that simple to change the role of a user.

Comment: I can't tell you for sure as I've never used a multi-tenant application with RBAC. As far as I know, if the authentication has multi-tenant enabled, all users under the specified tenants can log in to the application. You could try it by logging in with an account and checking if it works. Then you could try assigning roles or groups to that email address, the process is probably the same: Active Directory - Enterprise applications - All applications - Your App - Users and groups - Add user/group.